# Highlighting problem with Javascript: changes differently

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var wordsToBeTyped = document.querySelector('h2').innerHTML.split('');
var place = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var correct = 0;
document.onkeydown = function(event) {

  if (event.key === wordsToBeTyped[place]) {
    correct = correct + 1;

    place = place + 1;
    document.getElementById('correct').innerHTML = 'Correct: You have ' + correct + ' correct!'

  } else {

    wrong = wrong + 1;
    document.getElementById('wrong').innerHTML = 'Wrong: You have ' + wrong + ' wrong'
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'skyblue'
    }, 500)
  }
  highlight(wordsToBeTyped[place])
}
highlight(wordsToBeTyped[place])

function highlight(text) {
  var inputText = document.querySelector('#checking');
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="google" content="notranslate">
  <title>Typing Accuracy Test</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Typing Accuracy Test</h1>
  <h2 id="checking">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tritani debitis ea ius, nostrud albucius vis eu. civibus consequuntur cum ut, te albucius accusamus per, illum nominati temporibus nec eu. adversarium efficiantur ei qui. at vix falli tollit. an graece vituperata vix, iusto
    primis ponderum id eum, delenit definiebas vix in.</h2>
  <h3 id="correct"></h3>
  <h3 id="wrong"></h3>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This code is supposed to run and highlight what you have typed so far. But, after to type toward the m, it just shows the span, instead of highlighting it. It is annoying, and I have tried to change the text to no spaces, but that doesn't work either. Above is my code. Thanks. It highlights everything after the m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few errors here...

Avoid playing with `innerHTML` as much as you can. `innerHTML` as a getter will return all the markup in your Element, and as a setter will remove all the nodes that were inside it.

For you this is a problem because you do change the innerHTML of your Element: at every character, you are converting the next letter to be typed as a `<span class="highlithed">`. So when you check the indexOf the character  (space), you find the one you did add in this markup.

To avoid that, use the `textContent` property of your Element, which will disregard all the markup.
But also, don't use `indexOf` to know where you are, it will still fail when a character was present before. So simply use the `place` counter you already have.

```js
// grab textContent
var wordsToBeTyped = document.querySelector('h2').textContent.split('');
var place = 0;
var wrong = 0;
var correct = 0;
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.key === wordsToBeTyped[place]) {
    correct = correct + 1;

    place = place + 1;
    // set textContent
    document.getElementById('correct').textContent = 'Correct: You have ' + correct + ' correct!'
  } else {
    wrong = wrong + 1;
    // set textContent
    document.getElementById('wrong').textContent = 'Wrong: You have ' + wrong + ' wrong'
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'skyblue'
    }, 500)
  }
  highlight(wordsToBeTyped[place])
}
highlight(wordsToBeTyped[place])

function highlight(text) {
  var inputText = document.querySelector('#checking');
  // grab textContent
  var innerText = inputText.textContent;
  if (place >= 0) {
    innerText = "<span class='highlight'>" + innerText.substring(0, place) + innerText.substring(place, place + text.length) + "</span>" + innerText.substring(place + text.length);
    // here you can set innerHTML
    inputText.innerHTML = innerText;
  }
}
```

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Typing Accuracy Test</h1>
<h2 id="checking">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, tritani debitis ea ius, nostrud albucius vis eu. civibus consequuntur cum ut, te albucius accusamus per, illum nominati temporibus nec eu. adversarium efficiantur ei qui. at vix falli tollit. an graece vituperata vix, iusto
  primis ponderum id eum, delenit definiebas vix in.</h2>
<h3 id="correct"></h3>
<h3 id="wrong"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for pure text change, and you are not taking account for position of your `place`. You should specify as text, not `innerHTML`. Perhaps you should parse `wordsToBeTyped` as a DOM Element and grab it's inner text value instead.